# Load a package as optional argument

Tags: conditionals, package-writing, package-options

I'm creating my personal package. I'd like to use an option to turn on/off the line numbering provided by the package `lineno`.

So, my `sty` file contains

```
\RequirePackage{lineno}
\linenumbers
```

But if one does not have the `lineno` package installed it will produce an error. It one does have the package installed it will enumerate the lines.

I'd like to check if one does have `lineno` first and in affirmative case I'd like to be able to use my package as

```
\usepackage[lineno]{mysty} % to turn on the numbering
```

or

```
\usepackage{mysty} % default with no numbering if `lineno` does not exists
```

I tried this

```
\RequirePackage{lineno}
\@ifpackageloaded{lineno}{%
\DeclareOption{lineno}{\linenumbers}%
\ProcessOptions%
}{}
```

and it works if `lineno` is installed. But what about if it is not?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Files can be tested via `\IfFileExists{file}{yes}{no}`.
- The following snipset uses a switch `\if@mysty@lineno` that remembers the option setting `lineno` for package `mysty`. Package `lineno` and `\linenumbers` are only executed, if the option `lineno` was given. This way, the package `lineno` is not loaded unnecessarily if it is not needed.
- Packages cannot be loaded during the option part of package files
  (because it would lead to reentrance problems of LaTeX's option code).

Snipset for package `mysty`:

```
\newif\if@mysty@lineno % default: false

% Option declarations of package `mysty'

\IfFileExists{lineno.sty}{%
  \DeclareOption{lineno}{\@mysty@linenotrue}%
}{%
  \DeclareOption{lineno}{%
    \PackageWarning{mysty}{Package lineno is not installed}%
  }%
}

% Execute package options
\ProcessOptions

% Afterwards it is again safe to load packages
\if@mysty@lineno
  \RequirePackage{lineno}\relax
  \linenumbers
\fi
```

**Answer to comment:**

LaTeX's implementation of `\IfFileExists` puts the second and third argument in a macro definition. Therefore further definitions with parameters in this arguments make trouble, because the `#` would need doubling. The following
workaround can be used:

```
\IfFileExists{color.sty}\@firstoftwo\@secondoftwo{%
  \RequirePackage{color}\relax
  \newcommand*{\alert}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}%
}{%
  \newcommand*{\alert}[1]{\textbf{#1}}%
}
```

Comment: I'm comparing your solution with @egregs one. I understand that both work and they only differ on the sequence of statements, that is, they are logically equivalent. Do you agree or do you see some advantage/disadvantage? Thanks.

Comment: @Sigur Both solutions are not logically equivalent, but pretty much similar. `egreg`'s solution only tests for the file, if needed -- in my case the warning is given earlier. (I would have deleted my solution, but my answer has more remarks/hints.)

Comment: Why is `\IfFileExists{color.sty}{\RequirePackage{color}\def\alerta#1{\textcolor{red}{#1}}}{}` producing the error **Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a {}**?

Comment: @Sigur "Suboptimal" implementation of `\IfFileExists` in the LaTeX kernel. Instead of `\IfFileExists{file}{yes}{no}` the workaround `\IfFileExists{file}\@firstoftwo\@secondoftwo{yes}{no}` can be used. Here `\IfFileExists{color.sty}\@firstofone\@gobble{\RequirePackage{color}\newcommand*{\alerta}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}}` can be used.

Answer (score 8):

Here's what you can put in `mysty.sty`:

```
\newif\ifmysty@lineno
\DeclareOption{lineno}{\mysty@linenotrue}

[...]

\ProcessOptions\relax

[...]

\ifmysty@lineno
  \IfFileExists{lineno.sty}
    {\RequirePackage{lineno}}
    {\PackageWarningNoLine{mysty}{You requested `lineno.sty' which\MessageBreak
       doesn't exist on your system}}
\fi
```

Then if you call `\usepackage[lineno]{mysty}` you'll load the package or will be warned it doesn't exist. Otherwise `lineno` won't be loaded.

Comment: Just a question: `\ifmysty@lineno` must have this format or it is only an easy way to remember some names? That is, is necessary to use `\if<name of the package>@<name of the option>`?

Comment: @Sigur The conditional can be named as you wish (so long as it begins with `if`). But it's common (and good) practice to use some kind of prefix for your package's commands to avoid name clashes.

Comment: Since the package default is not turn on the numbering we should use `\RequirePackage{lineno}\linenumbers`. Thanks.

Comment: A switch name that is defined by `\newif` must start with `\if`. The rest of the name is free. But `\newif` does not check, whether the name is already defined. Using the package name (or similar unique prefix) for internal commands make it easier to avoid name clashes.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Actually LaTeX doesn't enforce `\newif\if...`, but funny things happen if you say `\newif\foo`. ;-)

Comment: Funny?! Like what?

Comment: @egreg Yes, I should have used "should" instead of "must". `\newif` needs to define `\<foo>true` and `\<foo>false` for `\newif\if<foo>`. LaTeX just gobbles the first two characters from `if<foo>` to get `<foo>`. The implementation of plain TeX for `\newif` requires that the switch name starts with `if`. Otherwise it triggers a TeX error. In LaTeX the setter functions for `\newif\foo` would become `\otrue` and `\ofalse`.