# How to clean all personal commands?

Tags: package-writing

I'm trying to improve the answers to [my other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110802/14757) to create my personal package which provides some commands, like `\alert` to write in red color, or some options like `lineno` to turn on line numbering.

But what should I do when I send the `tex` file to someone who don't have the my personal style package?

Looking for a solution I tried to check before the document class if my package file exists. If yes, great, load it.

But the problem is in negative case. I should to redefine all personal commands or clean all of them to avoid errors.

What is the better way to do this?

Comment: Have a look at [pstool github version](https://github.com/wspr/pstool/blob/master/pstool.tex) which uses [filecontents](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/filecontents) i suppose. May be change title to represent content of Q as : Make a single LaTeX file including a `personal.sty` with its de­pen­den­cies. Just incase [Yiannis's Answer to "Best practice on organising your preamble"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40785/15717)

Comment: If you really must only send one file (and don't want to include all you style files via `filecontents`) then you can add user level macros in the `.tex` file you send such as `\providecommand{\alert}[1]{#1}`. This way the `.tex` file can be compiled without having access to your personal `.sty` files. I do this for the case where I do not load the `lineno` package, but don't want to test everyplace where I need to use the related commands. So, for the case where I do _not_ load that package I have a `\providecommand` to define the usual `lineno` macros to have no effect.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`snapshot`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/snapshot) and [`bundledoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bundledoc) to bundle all necessary files to compile your document.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just send them the package with all of the other .tex files and images that you will send them?

Or, use a site like writelatex.com, where you can share all of your files online with collaborators?

Comment: Some people don't like to work with more than one file, specially if they are from old school.

Comment: I wrote that and then realised I had spectacularly failed to answer the question. Ho hum.