# Load package as optional argument

Tags: packages, conditionals

This is somehow related to this [Load a package as optional argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110802/load-a-package-as-optional-argument):

I'm trying to load geometry package as optional, meaning: if is defined in preamble should be load with my margins, if not document will have the default geometry of article, book, report etc.

*I have to mention that I'm not a programmer at all*, but in my mind what I have wrote in MWE makes sens :). Basicaly I'm trying to **find a formula (for my Humanistic mind)** -- i.e. in simple steps, to load some packages with my specifications when I need them.

I would also appreciate some %%% comments %%% on the code, because I want to understand and to reproduce on other packages that I want to load.

---

With my code, margins are changing, but not with my specs...

---

#### The MWE

```
% !TEX program = pdflatex
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{testpckg}
%\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{filecontents}[force]{testpckg.sty}


\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{testpckg}[2021/02/26 Test package]

\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%\RequirePackage{xstring}   
%\RequirePackage{geometry}
    
    % -- if specified in preamble load with this specs
\newif\iftestpckg@geometry
\DeclareOption{geometry}{%
    \testpckg@geometrytrue
    \geometry{top=.5cm,bottom=.5cm,right=.5cm,left=.5cm} % <-- just for better visualization
    }
    \ProcessOptions
    \iftestpckg@geometry
    \RequirePackage{geometry} % <-- else load default geometry from article, book, report...
    \fi
    
\end{filecontents}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\kant

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can't actually prevent users from loading `geometry` themselves and choose their own parameters.

Comment: @egreg can you please elaborate? Because I can choose my own parameters if I specify optional arguments [margin=2.5cm].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
% !TEX program = pdflatex
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8

\begin{filecontents}[force]{testpckg.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{testpckg}[2021/02/26 Test package]

\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newif\iftestpckg@geometry

\DeclareOption{geometry}{\testpckg@geometrytrue}
\ProcessOptions

\RequirePackage{geometry}

\iftestpckg@geometry
  \geometry{top=.5cm,bottom=.5cm,right=.5cm,left=.5cm}
\fi
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{testpckg}
%\geometry{margin=5cm}

\begin{document}
 \kant 
\end{document}
```

With `\usepackage{testpckg}` you will get:

[image]

With `\usepackage[geometry]{testpckg}` you will get:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Can I use your model to other packages?

Comment: Yes, of course. But just to be honest I wouldn't call it "mine" or even a "model" ;-) As a suggestion I recommend starting from an existing package to understand how to handle the options. At least I do that